# ALSA tutorial required

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

I am New to audio programming.I want to create small application which is capable of playing and gives volume control . I am using alsa-lib.

I want to know what is the purpose of switch (ex.Master Playback switch), enum in mixer elements and what value should i set to those switchs .

Please suggest me some tutorial for mixer settings as well as alsa programming .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just collecting some here, that have example code:

- [ALSA Programming HOWTO v.1.0.0 [alsamodular.sourceforge.net]](http://alsamodular.sourceforge.net/alsa_programming_howto.html)
- [A tutorial on using the ALSA Audio API [equalarea.com]](http://equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html) 2002
- [A close look at ALSA [volkerschatz.com]](http://www.volkerschatz.com/noise/alsa.html)
- [ALSA API - Sample Programs With Source Code By Aquiles Yanez](http://alumnos.elo.utfsm.cl/~yanez/alsa-sample-programs/) 2005
- [Introduction to Sound Programming with ALSA | Linux Journal (pg3 with example code)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,2) 2004

Note that some of these are old, and API may have changed in the meantime... you can also look up `aplay.c` (the source for the command line `arecord` and `aplay`), but that one is not the easiest to read for starters...

Answer (score 7):

You'll have a tough time finding anything concrete on ALSA, as I have have found from just starting learning it too. The best place to begin is the [ALSA project homepage](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Tutorials_and_Presentations) where they link to a number of tutorials, the best one being Dr Nagorni's one IMO.

From what it sounds like you're trying to do, [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) would most likely be a quicker and easier solution, though.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the docs. There are some good examples.

http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/examples.html

Be aware of the safe alsa subset.

https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2009-June/179698.html

Here's something small I put together using the various sources I could find. It miiiiiiiiiight be a good starting point.

```
/* Compile with gcc -lasound -pthread threadaudio.c */

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char audiobuffer[0x400];
pthread_mutex_t audiomutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void changeaudio (int volume) {
  int i;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&audiomutex);
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(audiobuffer); i++)
    audiobuffer[i] = (random() & 0xff) * volume / 10;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&audiomutex);
}

void *startaudio (void *param)
{
  static char *device = "default";
  snd_output_t *output = NULL;
  int *audiostop = (int*)param;
  int err;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;

  changeaudio(5);

  if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_set_params(handle,
                SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8,
                SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED,
                1,
                48000,
                1,
                100000)) < 0) {   /* 0.1sec */
    printf("Playback open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (!*audiostop) {
    err = snd_pcm_wait(handle, 1000);
    if (err < 0) {
      fprintf (stderr, "poll failed (%d)\n", err);
      break;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&audiomutex);
    frames = snd_pcm_writei(handle, audiobuffer, sizeof(audiobuffer));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&audiomutex);

    if (frames < 0)
      err = snd_pcm_recover(handle, frames, 0);
    if (err < 0) {
      printf("snd_pcm_writei failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
      break;
    }

    if (frames > 0 && frames < (long)sizeof(audiobuffer))
      printf("Short write (expected %li, wrote %li)\n", (long)sizeof(audiobuffer), frames);
  }
  snd_pcm_close(handle);  
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t audiothread;
  int audiostop = 0;
  int volume;

  pthread_create(&audiothread, NULL, startaudio, &audiostop);

  while (1) {
    printf("Enter volume 1 through 10. [0 to quit.]: ");
    scanf("%d", &volume);
    if (volume == 0) break;
    changeaudio(volume);
  }

  audiostop = 1;
  pthread_join(audiothread, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

And after reading the code above you'll probably want to read this article regarding (among other things) not using locks.

http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing